# Different behaviour of javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button and I am changing its value and name on click showing same value in alert. Its working fine when I use jQuery but not when I use call function with JavaScript function value is not changing in front view but in alert value is changing its totally strange.

Here are the demos

**JavaScript**

```js
function change() {
  if ($(this).attr('name') == 'first') {
    $(this).attr('name', 'second');
    $(this).attr('value', 'second');
    alert('new name ' + $(this).attr('name'));
  } else {
    $(this).attr('name', 'first');
    $(this).attr('value', 'first');
    alert('new name ' + $(this).attr('name'));
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="button" value="first" name="first" onclick="change()">
```

**jQuery**

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('name') == 'first') {
    $(this).attr('name', 'second');
    $(this).attr('value', 'second');
    alert('new name ' + $(this).attr('name'));
  } else {
    $(this).attr('name', 'first');
    $(this).attr('value', 'first');
    alert('new name ' + $(this).attr('name'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="button" value="first" name="first">
```

I know I can use jQuery as I am already including the library but I so much wanted to know what is the difference between these two.

Comment: Er... Never change `name` of input. General thumb rule.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Use `val("value")` instead of `attr("value","value")`

Comment: Both of them are jQuery

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy this can be done but `attr("value","value")` will also not create errors

Comment: @GauravAggarwal You are just setting the attribute. It doesn't change the value.

Comment: @Sree i know and i already mentioned in question i am including jquery for both but its all about calling function by jQuery or javascript

Comment: @PraveenKumar but if you check Dhara Parmar answer below he is also setting the attribute only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `this` to change function so that you can access the clicked object inside that function, `.click()` event of any element will automatically detect `$(this`)  but in function you need to pass it

Pass `this` in `change()` function in button:

```
<input type="submit" id="button" value="first" name="first"  onclick="change(this)">
```

So change function will have:

```js
function change(obj) {
  if ($(obj).attr('name') == 'first') {
    $(obj).attr('name', 'second');
    $(obj).attr('value', 'second');
    alert('new name ' + $(obj).attr('name'));
  } else {
    $(obj).attr('name', 'first');
    $(obj).attr('value', 'first');
    alert('new name ' + $(obj).attr('name'));
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="button" value="first" name="first"  onclick="change(this)">
```

Comment: Explanation being, `change()` is bound (sets "`this`") to the `window`, not the button, so you need to pass it to the function to access it. In the second example, jquery binds the function to the button, so `$(this)` is as you expect

Comment: @GauravAggarwal  You need to pass this to change function so that you can access the clicked object inside that function...click event of any element will automatically detect $(this).. but in function you need to pass it

Answer (score 0):

passing 'this' to the function and using it instead of 'this' inside the function solves your problem.

because using 'this' inside a function not handled by Jquery event, returns the owner of the function that is an object of the button you have while in jquery it returns a jQuery object

```js
function change(btn){
 if($(btn).attr('name') == 'first'){
   $(btn).attr('name','second');
    $(btn).attr('value','second');
    alert('new name '+$(btn).attr('name'));
  } else {
   $(btn).attr('name','first');
   $(btn).attr('value','first');
    alert('new name '+$(btn).attr('name'));
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="button" value="first" name="first"  onclick="change(this)">
```